# MacBook Pro (13-inch non-retina mid2012) won't turn on after connecting a Raspberry Pi to it using a USB cable

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, power, magsafe

I was working with my Raspberry Pi Pico, connecting it to my MacBook Pro (13-inch non-retina display mid 2012, running macOS Catalina) using a USB cable (with the other end being a micro USB). Everything was OK and I ran the code I had written (which was a simple LED blink, to test the Pi) successfully and it worked, but suddenly my Mac went off and it didn't turn on again.

I tried disconnecting all the peripherals (including the MagSafe power adapter & the USB cable itself) immediately after this happened, but still it didn't turn on. I kept holding the power button for ~10 seconds, and tried again, but it didn't work either.
I also tried to reset SMC, but that one didn't work.
It's also notable that the LED battery indicator on the left of the body of the Mac doesn't work. Neither does the LED on the MagSafe.

What has happened and what should I do now? Have I bricked my Mac? Or just the battery is broken?

Comment: From which year is the MBP?

Comment: 2012 I presume, I bought it about 12 years ago.

Comment: “MD101” refers to a range of MacBook Pro units.  Can you supply just the year and size with an [edit]?  That is more than sufficient.   Hold the power button for a full 30 seconds.  The next option would be to disconnect the battery and reconnect it.  Failing that, you might  have a toasted logic board.

Comment: Sure, I made an edit. It's a 13-inch non-retina display mid 2012. I'm thinking of the reconnecting option, because the 30 second thing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Leave the battery disconnected for at least 30 seconds to dissipate  power - you can even hold down the power button to be sure. Then reconnect.  One thing you might want to try *before* hooking up your battery is to plug in the MagSafe.  See if you get fan spin.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! Will try later. Got a little frustrated now.

Comment: I’ve been there.  Going forward either use a Bluetooth to UART adapter or use a USB hub.  You want to isolate your *expensive* computer from unintended surges and short circuits when tinkering.  It’s much cheaper and easier to fix a USB hub than a MacBook logic board.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, everything is now working perfectly! My Mac is back.